# Declaring an object that implements an interface

Tags: java, class, generics, interface, implements

I'm trying to declare an object which must implement a specific interface.
I thought the following would work in Java as it does in some other languages but I'm at a loss here:

```
Class<? implements **theInterface**> implementingObject
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for generics, you use "extends" regardless of whether it is a Class or Interface.

```
Class<? extends **theInterface**> implementingObject
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are declaring here isn't an object that implements an interface, but a **class of** an object which implements that interface. An object implementing an interface is simply declared as the interface type, i.e.

```
theInterface implementingObject;
```